# Get x and y coords of image crop after scaling image up

Tags: javascript, jquery, image-processing

I am scaling an image up and cropping it, but my x and y coordinates always seem to be slightly off compared to my selection. I think I'm scaling X and Y wrong, but I'm not sure what else to try.

```
var zoom = 1.5; //set dynamically by the user; ranges from 0.1 to infinity                  
var xPercent = cropDetails.x / imageW; // find how far x is from the left, relative to its size
var yPercent = cropDetails.y / imageH; // find how far y is from the top, relative to its size
var newImageSize = {width: imageW * zoom, height: imageH * zoom}; //find zoomed image width and height
cropDetails.x = newImageSize.width * xPercent; //find new x value for the resized image
cropDetails.y = newImageSize.height * yPercent; //find new y value for the resized image
```

EDIT: Kind of like [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/601186/correct-the-position-of-a-rectangle-after-scaling-it), but I don't want the inner rectangle to scale in size.

**Multiplying X and Y by zoom:**

Pre-crop, zoomed to 190%
[image: Pre-crop, zoomed to 190%]

Post-crop, seems like it's down and to the right
[image: Post-crop, seems like it's down and to the right]

I also get the same result when I scale the coordinates proportionally.

Answer (score 1):

You are finding the relative positions of x and y in your image. Then, you find the same relative points in a larger image. Seems correct but needlessly complex. Could rounding error be a problem? Are you setting the width and height of your crop anywhere?

You can actually find the new x and y points by scaling their locations by the zoom. e.g. the point (20, 20) in a (100, 100) image is in the same place as the point (30, 30) in the (150, 150) image. Thus, just multiply the coordinates, width, and height of your crop details by the zoom and you should be good!

```
var zoom = 1.5;              
cropDetails.x *= zoom;
cropDetails.y *= zoom;
cropDetails.width *= zoom;
cropDetails.height *= zoom;
var newImageSize = {width: imageW * zoom, height: imageH * zoom};
```

Try that and let me know if it works! If not, you should post some examples of how it's failing so that I can help you debug.